# What will be the complexity of this code? Should we sum complexities?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

I have an algorithm which ,at first, sorts the vector and then iterate through its elements and `XOR` them. Should I sum the complexities of sort and for loop to calculate the overall algorithm complexity?
So, I have next code:

```
std::sort(array.begin(), array.end());
for (int i =1; i < array.size(); ++i) {
  result = array[i-1]^array[i];
}
```

We have a for loop which has `O(N)` complexity and `std::sort` which has `O(N log N)` comparisons on the average.
So the complexity of the next code will be `O(N + N log N)`?
Or in this case we just have to choose the highest time complexity class which is linearithmic time `O(N log N)` and don't sum them?

Comment: Its still O(n lgn)

Comment: ***for (int i =1; i <= array.size(); ++i) {*** You have UB when you access `array[i]` in the next line when i = array.size().

Comment: how do you equate `N+N logN` to `2NlogN`?

Comment: @drescherjm Can you please explain why? Pre-increment?

Comment: `array[array.size()]` is out of bounds. look when i== array.size(). result = array[array.size()-1]^array[array.size()]

Comment: @Arunmu Because complexities don't sum? We just select the highest?

Comment: O(Elephant + Mosquito) = O(Elephant)

Comment: @tobi303 Thanks for the tip. I was wrong here.

Comment: @MainstreamDeveloper00  EricDuminil has summed it up pretty well. And we do that because with 'O' we are looking for an _upper_ bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The runtime is bounded by the sorting step, `O(nlgn)`. The for loop may have `O(n)` complexity, but the overall runtime is always dominated by the highest power. See here for a mathematical proof:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324200/big-o-notation-sum-rule

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can sum them: `O(n)` and `O(n log n)` becomes `O(n + n log n)`.  But note this is *not* `O(2n log n)` as you suggest, because addition comes after multiplication in basic arithmetic.

Now, just as `O(1 + n)` is always reduced to `O(n)`, your `O(n + n log n)` will be reduced to `O(n log n)` because the solitary `n` term is less than the `n log n` term, and big-O notation is always about the limits, not the exact equation.

Some people might find it more intuitive to recognize from the outset that `O(n)` is dominated by `O(n log n)`, and never sum them in the first place.  That's a useful mental shortcut, but both perspectives get you the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The complexity class `O(N)` is a subset of the class `O(N log N)`, since `log N > 1` for sufficiently high `N`. Thus, the complexity class of the code `O(N + N log N)` is a subset of `O(2 N log N)`, and since the complexity classes are invariant w.r.t. constants, it's `O(N log N)` at the end.

Comment: Why the down-vote? Explain.

Answer (score 0):

The way we calculate complexities is by choosing the highest among all the ones.

So, lets suppose you have the following code

```
for i in range 0 to n
{
    for  in range 0 to n
    {
        \\ code
    }
}

for i in range 0 to n
{
    \\ code
}
```

So, here there the complexities would be `O(n^2) + O(n)`. Which would finally be `O(n^2)`. So, the complexity of the whole above code is `O(n^2)`.

---

Similarly, in your case the complexity is `O(N log N) + O(N)`, which makes the final complexity to be `O(N log N)`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `O(N+N log N)` would not give you `O(2N log N)`, it would give you      `O( (log N+1) * N)`.  This algorithm would be bounded by `O(N log N)`, as this grows faster than `O(N)` as N approaches infinity.